# MD5 (OSX) and Output

Tags: macos, terminal, md5, automator

when using MD5 i get a text file output of the full path to the file and file name and then space and the hash.

wondering if there's a way omit the path and just have filename = hash

using terminal via automator

---

```
find "$1" -type f -print0 | xargs -0 md5 > "$2/MD5_Digest.md5"
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `-q` command-line switch to make the output "quiet"

```
$ md5 -q my_file_to_test
d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
$
```